# Django response send file as well as some text data

Tags: django-rest-framework, download, python-3.6, response, django-2.0

Currently I am send a zip file in response from my Django-Rest controller, the zip file will get downloaded in front-end and this feature is working fine but now I want to send some data as well with the zip file in response, is there any way?

This is my Django-REST controller code

```
response = HttpResponse(byte_io.getvalue(),content_type='application/x-zip-compressed')

response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment;filename{my-sample-zip-file}'

return response
```

How can I send some data with this zip file on front-end?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with HTTP Request-Response module of django.
Refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment

If you want to do it in production like code, you might also want to handle case where file is not available, set error and return neat. Also, better put that in a common file and then define download_file like below:

```
from common_library import FileResponse
from django.http import JsonResponse

    def download_file( self ):
    if self.error_response:
        response = JsonResponse( { "error" : self.error_response } ) 
    else:    
        response = FileResponse(self.report_file_abs_path,  self.report_filename)
        response['Content-Type'] = 'application/xlsx'
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + self.report_filename
    return response
```

NOTE: FileResponse is a user defined wrapper function which you can define.